# How do I install Ubuntu on my iBook G3?

Tags: installation, mac, powerpc

How can I download Ubuntu on my PC, burn it to a disk, and install it on my iBook G3?

Comment: To whomever downvoted this: This is a good question, perfectly on-topic. :)

Answer (score 1):

For an iBook G3, which has a PowerPC CPU you need the PowerPC port of Ubuntu. I believe the latest release that supported PPC is 10.10, and would probably be better off with 10.04 (since it has LTS support).

The ISOs can be found here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ports/releases/ And the image needed would be the powerpc images.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, I was not thinking about this when writing my answer. My apologies.

Comment: No worries, William :-) Just didn't want the OP to get confused and/or frustrated.

Comment: Agreed. First-time impressions are big.=)

Comment: @William if your answer isn't useful you can always just delete it!

Comment: I know, but the answer is still helpful to those who don't know how to install Ubuntu on a standard, 32-bit machine.

Comment: @JaysonRowe when replying to someone else's answer please use a comment, instead of another answer. Your answer is fine otherwise.

Comment: @William even if it helps others, it will not help those coming to _this_ question.  Use the answer for another question where it is correct.

Comment: @JaysonRowe you should revise this answer to just answer the question .  A pointer to the right ISO will hopefully be just what the OP needs.

Comment: Answer revised - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I will delete my post. First I want to save my answer somewhere, because it might be useful for someone else. I have to get to my computer to copy stuff, then I'll delete this post. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Links for the PPC downloads are maintained on this page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads .  The one for xubuntu 10.04 is missing though so I'll give it to you here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/ports/releases/lucid/release/

For 11.04 and 11.10 you'll have to install via the mini.iso.  There are detailed instructions linked on the downloads page.  For a G3 ibook you may prefer to install lubuntu or xubuntu.