# How to burn ubuntu to a cd and make it bootable

Tags: apple

I need help with burning Ubuntu to a CD and being able to boot it into a PC, and an old iBook. I have already downloaded the ISO file, and have burned it to a CD.

However when I try to load it, it doesn't work.

I would also need help when it boots up. I would like to perform the procedure on a PC too.

Comment: First of all, don't expect answers per email. People who can answer will do so on this page, down below. You also really need to provide some more information. "Doesn't work" is not helpful at all. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Is it an iBook G3? If it is, [this is a duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/q/77748/12864).

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using *Ubuntu* -**

If you are using Ubuntu itself to create the bootable CD/DVD, use [k3b](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/k3b) [image: Install k3b] instead of [brasero](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/brasero) [image: Install brasero].

After you install and start K3b select the option **Burn Image** as seen below in the image-

[image: K3b image burn]

After that click on the **Open File Dialog** option as seen below and then select the iso image by browsing to it.

[image: select image]

**If you are using *Windows* -**

If you are using Windows to create the bootable CD/DVD i suggest using [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/?page_id=5)  instead of Nero.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) is the official step by step tutorial which teaches you how to burn an ISO on to a DVD to make it bootable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of burning the .iso to disc as a file, you need to tell your burning software to burn it as an image instead.

Answer (score 0):

Burn it using the slowest speed setting possible.  Also, make sure to "Burn" it.  If you just copy the iso file, it will not be bootable.

If that does not work, we may need to check the MD5 checksum to make sure the iso file is good.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest possible way to burn a iso in Linux according to me , is to use cdrecord. 
Just the following command in the shell:

```
cdrecord youisofile.iso
```