# how to run Xubuntu download

Tags: livedvd

I have downloaded the Xubuntu 14.04.3 Desktop i386 ISO from the official site and don't know what else to do so I can start using this OS instead of the Windows XP currently installed on my HP 6730s laptop. When I double left click on the downloaded file Windows says it doesn't know what to use for opening it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to burn ubuntu to a cd and make it bootable](http://askubuntu.com/questions/185895/how-to-burn-ubuntu-to-a-cd-and-make-it-bootable)

Answer (score 1):

An ISO file is an "image" of a disc - this is, a virtual copy of a CD/DVD/BD that you can use to record or "burn" new discs. In order to install any (GNU)Linux distribution (commonly known as "*Linux* systems"), you first have to download the installer's ISO and then burn it using a recording software.

There are two ways you can get your copy of the Xubuntu installer working:

1. Burn to a CD or DVD using i.e. [CDBurnerXP](https://cdburnerxp.se), [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org) or [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/).
2. Burn to an USB drive with [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/), [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) or [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/)

These programs let you choose a file and then record it into the device you wish. I recommend you to use CDBurnerXP and Universal USB Installer, since they are reliable and straight-forward.

Since it seems that this is the first time you're trying to install an OS by yourself, why don't you check a tutorial on installing (X)ubuntu? 
[Here's the official one!](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)